# Стрельба на опережение

Tags: python, разработка-игр

Кратко опишу проблему. Есть поле (плоскость, по которой в любых направлениях двигаются объекты), герой (он передвигается по полю в соответствием нажатия игроком клавиш) и бот (он должен стоять на месте и стрелять в героя).

У героя нам известны: координаты (x, y) и скорость движения (она постоянная).

У бота нам известны: координаты (x, y) и скорость его пули.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы научить бота стрелять на опережение. То есть, я могу заставить бота стрелять в какую-то точку (могу привести код, если нужно); но в случае, если эта точка двигается, вероятность попасть в нее очень мала.

Для удобства приведу входные и выходные данные:

ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ: скорость движения пули и героя, текущие координаты героя, координаты бота.

ВЫХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ: направление(от 0 до 360 градусов), в котором должна полететь пуля бота (разумеется, начальный xy пули совпадает с xy бота); ИЛИ координаты того места, куда должен целиться бот, чтобы попасть в героя

Мне нужна формула по входным данным (код на python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно решать систему уравнений относительно неизвестных `t` и `f`

```
hx0 + hvx * t = bx0 + bv * cos(f) * t
hy0 + hvy * t = by0 + bv * sin(f) * t
```

hx0 - x-координата героя
hvx - x-компонент скорости героя
bx0 - x-координата пушки
bv - значение скорости пули
t - время
f - угол пушки

Maple подсказывает, что можно найти `t` как корень квадратного уравнения

```
(hvy^2+hvx^2-bv^2) * t^2 + 
(2*hvy*hy0+2*hx0*hvx-2*by0*hvy-2*hvx*bx0) * t +
(hy0^2+by0^2-2*hy0*by0+bx0^2-2*hx0*bx0+hx0^2) = 0
```

и подставить его для нахождения угла.

Подставив `t` в первое уравнение, найдём косинус, а из второго - синус, из их комбинации уже вычислим угол

```
f = atan2(sin(f), cos(f))
```

(Если использовать, например, только косинус и взять арккосинус - то получим результат с точностью до знака)

Comment: Хорошо хоть, что ТС-у не нужно учитывать гравитацию и сопротивление воздуха (зависящее от высоты и скорости пули)

Comment: Хорошо, допустим я нашел время, решив квадратное уравнение, но дальше мне нужно решить еще и систему? Или я должен просто подставить t в любое из уравнений системы? Ведь уравнение будет тогда с одной переменной.

Comment: Да, можно подставить t в любое из уравнений, потом нужно только уточнить, какое из значений арккосинуса или арксинуса использовать. Или сразу atan2 - добавил в ответ

Comment: А какой из корней нужно выбирать? Ведь в квадратном уравнении их 2 получается.

Comment: Я понял, нужно выбирать корень, где корень из дискриминанта вычитается; только в этом случае все работает. Большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Логика такая - нужен корень (t) с положительным значением. Если их два - выбирается меньший.

Comment: А если 2 отрицательных?

Comment: Подозреваю, что два отрицательных по физической природе задачи не получатся. Нет решений - пуля не догоняет.  Два положительных   - два возможных угла прицеливания - на встречном курсе и вдогон. Одно отрицательное, другое положительное - момент времени в прошлом и будущем (момент встречного выстрела уже пропущен).

Comment: Однако, когда я запускал программу, то выводил в консоль корни, и было такое, когда они оба отрицательны. Я не знаю с чем это связанно, но тот t, где корень из дискриминанта прибавляется, никогда не подходит по условию; и в любом случае правелен оказывается только тот t, при нахождении которого мы вычитаем корень из дискриминанта.

Comment: Ну я чисто умозрительно рассуждал, мог где-то в рассуждениях или в знаке проколоться